# Normal vector from equation question

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

Why if you have a equation of a plane, say $2x + 3y - z = 20$, if you take it's coefficients you have the components of it's normal vector? In most text books and exercises I've done so far this relation is given but I want to understand better, the intuition, why you can have an orthogonal vector from the equation of a plane. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two points in the plane, say $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$. Then we know that 
\begin{align}
2x_1 + 3y_1 - z_1 &= 20 \\
2x_2 + 3y_2 - z_2 &= 20 \\
\end{align}
so subtracting, we have
\begin{align}
2(x_1 - x_2) + 3(y_1-y_2) - (z_1 - z_2) &= 0, \text{ or}\\
\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\-1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x_1 - x_2\\y_1 - y_2\\z_1 - z_2\end{bmatrix} = 0.\end{align}

That says that the vector $(2, 3, -1)$ is perpendicular to the vector between any two points of the plane, i.e., is perpendicular to every vector *in* the plane. Hence it's the normal vector to the plane (up to a constant multiple).